# Cannot get auto-slide to work on one of my sliders

Tags: php, css, responsive-design, slider, web-testing

I have a homepage being developed at: http://www.spark-creative.ca/exp_clean/index_new.php

There is a slider in the body that shows Hitachi and Microsoft logos. I need that slider to auto-slide at set intervals, but I cannot see where to set that to do it. My developer cannot find it either. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change something here(line: 1202):

```
$('#main-slider,#main-slider1,#main-slider2,#main-slider3,#main-slider4,#main-slider5,#main-slider6,#main-slider7,#main-slider8').liquidSlider({});
```

Try the **continuous: true** setting for the respective sliders, you can find it in the docs..

[Sliding Options](http://liquidslider.com/documentation/#sliding-options)